# How do I bring a Mii to help my Mii that is trapped in the cage?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-quest-find-mii

I just started playing *Find Mii* on the 3DS and I can't get very far at all. When I hire a wanderer most of the time it just runs away from the thing it encounters and then I have to use coins to get another one. At this rate I will never get far in this game. How do you get a Mii to play the game so I won't have to keep using my coins to hire a wanderer? I can't even seem to get any Mii's to come to my plaza via Street Pass in the first place. There was one Mii that I noticed was in my plaza but I couldn't use them to help in *Find Mii*.

Can someone explain how I can farther in this game because it's very boring and frustrating at the moment. Also how do I get more accessories for my Mii?

Comment: Only the first Hero in line will be frightened away without a chance to attack - so you should hire large groups of heros instead of one at a time.  Also, if you got Reggie (or Mr. Iwata) for the 1 year anniversary of the 3DS in February, you can re-hire him to fight in Find Mii II.

Answer (score 6):

In order to get Miis for use in *Puzzle Swap*, *Find Mii* and other games in *StreetPass Mii Plaza*, you must StreetPass with another 3DS owner, which basically means you have to be in wireless range with their system for long enough for the two to realize each others' presence. Once you do this their Mii will appear in the two games.

For *Find Mii* specifically, a Mii will be no more useful than a wandering hero, dealing 1 damage per hit and bolting for the hills soon after. You have to tag that 3DS multiple times for them to level up to increase their damage output. There is nothing you can do to stop a hero (wandering or Mii) from abandoning battle once they do something, unless they just sworded something to death or won the battle.

Miis you find in your plaza that aren't from StreetPass are those you've seen in other games, like the Miis you play online in *Mario Kart 7*. They're dead weight.

Mii accessories are earned by completing levels in *Find Mii* or by redeeming Plaza Tickets from the other downloadable games in *StreetPass Mii Plaza*. To get all of them you must play through the entire adventure multiple times.

**TL;DR:** One's fun with the *StreetPass Mii Plaza* is directly proportional to how many other 3DS's are in your daily stomping grounds. And this isn't even counting the artificial constraints (e.g. some battles in *Find Mii* are point-blank impassible without a certain colour of hero).

Comment: Going to a convention or similar gathering where lots of people will have 3DS's is _amazing_ for streetpasses. :P

Comment: I have good luck with StreetPass at movie openings; and theme parks, even local ones.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your great responses and advice. I will try these suggestions.

Comment: With the most recent 3DS update, you can now hire previously encountered heroes for Play Coins.